# PySpark query REST API without knowing scheme

Tags: rest, pyspark, azure-databricks

How can I format the PySpark struct types to reflect the following API json result? This is the complete result returned by the API call. Please note, the `coordinates` element has an unknown dynamic length prior to obtaining the json.

```
{'type': 'Polygon',
 'coordinates': [[[-74.53703811195342, 43.93214895162186],
   [-74.53765823498132, 43.932511606633376],
   [-74.53790321887529, 43.933052813967755],
...
   
   [-74.53653908240167, 43.93223696479821],
   [-74.53703811195342, 43.93214895162186]]]}
```

My attempt:

```
# set up UDF
schema = StructType([
    StructField("type", StringType()),
      StructField("coordinates", StringType()) # I just put a random StringType
])

# then after the API query,
result_df = request_df \
       .withColumn("result", udf_executeRestApi(col("body")))
df = result_df.select([col for col in result_df.columns])
df.show()
```

and got:

[image]

It's showing the Polygon object as expected, but formatted wrong. And the predefined `type` and `coordinates` are not recognised here.

Here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below schema for you REST Api response.

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("type", StringType()),
    StructField("coordinates", ArrayType(ArrayType(ArrayType(DoubleType()))))]) 

df = spark.createDataFrame([json_data], schema=schema)
display(df)
```

Output:

[image]

Also you need to check what your **udf** returns.
Give above schema as return type while registering udf and return your json data directly.If you provide your udf function it will help me to resolve this clearly.

Comment: Thank you, and apologies for the non reproducible example. The udf actually calls a complex function that I didn't define above, but should return the example json:

`udf_executeRestApi = udf(delineate_watershed, schema)`

Comment: Ok. As i mentioned use the schema given in the solution. That will work.

Comment: I have obtained the same result as show in the question after modifying the schema

Comment: what is the data you are returning from udf, is it data directly from rest api or done some modification?

Comment: I have added the result of `display(df)` in the description - maybe that is as good as it gets?

Comment: pre-defined types and coordinates are recognized i believe. can you able to see the data in dropdown as shown in solution or it is completely string?

Comment: I do have dropdowns

Comment: The schema that you have provided enabled the dropdowns. Thank you!